# Question mark is appeared as icon in react native application

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to use Icon into my react native project so i installed :

1.`npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`

2.`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

After this part all icons added to `android/app/sec/main/assets/fonts`:

```
ls -l /media/groot/Project/React\ Native/Practices/RNheader/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
total 1976
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  70344 Jan  9 16:45 AntDesign.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  65584 Jan  9 16:45 Entypo.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  13456 Jan  9 16:45 EvilIcons.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  58272 Jan  9 16:45 Feather.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 125016 Jan  9 16:45 FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  34092 Jan  9 16:45 FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 186228 Jan  9 16:45 FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 165548 Jan  9 16:45 FontAwesome.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 313528 Jan  9 16:45 Fontisto.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  56976 Jan  9 16:45 Foundation.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 112472 Jan  9 16:45 Ionicons.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 546548 Jan  9 16:45 MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot 128180 Jan  9 16:45 MaterialIcons.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  28364 Jan  9 16:45 Octicons.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  54056 Jan  9 16:45 SimpleLineIcons.ttf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 groot groot  25552 Jan  9 16:45 Zocial.ttf
```

3. I added to my js file like this:

   import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

This is my file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";


export default HeaderView = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.headerStyle} >
            <View style={styles.columnStyle}>
                <Icon name="arrow-back" size={15}/>

            </View>
            <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>)
}
```

but when i run project on android emulator the icon appears as `?` :
[image]

And i got this warning:

[image]

That is my mistake?

I think i added correct the name of icon:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `md-arrow-back` instead of `arrow-back`.

Reason as stated in the website of Iconicons,

> When using Ionicons without the Ionic Framework, the icon will default
>   to the Material Design icon style. To specify the non-default icon
>   style, add a platform prefix to the name attribute.

Which means if you are not using it in ionic framework, you have to add prefix which is `md` before any icon name.

You can check more in [usage page](https://ionicons.com/usage#md-arrow-back) of [Iconicons](https://ionicons.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This means that the name you have supplied **arrow-back** is not valid for that icon, change `name="arrow-back"` to `name="md-arrow-back"`. If you really want to use **arrow-back** import from **MaterialIcons** instead of **Ionicons**

Comment: Thanks bro . it's work but in the it's site i added above the name of icon assigned as "arrow-back"..Why?  and i used `Ionicons`  not `MaterialIcons`  `import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";`  @TebogoMahlalela

Comment: No idea why it does that it also happened to me earlier this week, then I imported from another directory and it worked. But in your case it showed the yellow box which means the problem was the name.

Comment: You don't know how could i use `Ionicons` ?

Comment: Just make sure your icon name matches any of the names under Ionicons directory from the site

Comment: Ok dude . look above image i use `arrow-back` from Ionicons but i got error ?What is exactly name of  "arrow-back" icon ?